# Koa2: how to write chain of middleware?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

So in express, we can have a chain of middleware, copies an example:

```
middleware = function(req, res){
  res.send('GET request to homepage');
});

app.get('/', middleware, function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to homepage');
});
```

What's the equivalent way to write this in koa2 please ?
I'm thinking of using it for the route, for each route i want to have a middleware to check if user is already logged in.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're simply interested in making sure a middlware runs for *every* route, all you have to do is register the middleware before you register your routing middelware.

```
app.use(middleware);
```

As long as you call this *before* you 'use' your router, it will be called for every request. Just make sure you call the next function. This is how your middleware might look like:

```
function middleware(ctx, next) {

   // Authenticate user

   // Eventually call this
   return next();

}
```

Comment: so i can chain middleware in this way as well ? How about i just want to apply middleware to certain routes ?

Comment: well, it's in the doc, router.use(session(), authorize());

// use middleware only with given path
router.use('/users', userAuth());

app.use(router.routes());