# How to apply middleware to all routes?

Tags: koa, koa2

How I want to apply middleware to all paths in koa-route, e.g.

```
router1.use( (ctx) => {
    console.error("hello 0 ...");
    console.log(ctx.url);
}
router1.all( (ctx) => {
    console.error("hello 0 ...");
    console.log(ctx.url);
}
```

It comes back like this
   path += str.slice(index, offset)
                ^

TypeError: str.slice is not a function
Any hints ? Thanks!

Comment: I just answered this question yesterday. Look there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Koa2: how to write chain of middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187902/koa2-how-to-write-chain-of-middleware)

Comment: @Evert think it's a little bit different, when I'm using koa-router, I don't want to go back use "app.", want to stay with "route.". Actually I hope I found a way, see my answer please. Let's discuss, :)

Comment: You should be fine with using app for this. koa-router is just another middleware. Your workaround might work, but it's a hack

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is it,

```
router1.use(/(.*)/, (ctx) => {
    console.error("hello 0 ...");
    console.log(ctx.url);
}
```